# How to speed up Open Folder "whose name starts with" in AppleScript

Tags: variables, path, applescript, alias, filenames

Here's my basic AppleScript...

I have a fixed file path, followed by 1 variable folder, followed by a variable partial folder name (ie variable folder starts with "12345").
What I failed to work out is how to open the target folder in 1 instruction (because it's a variable).  So I've had to open the enclosing folder, then do a "get folders whose name starts with".  This is where my script is VERY slow. The target folder contains a couple of thousand folders, so searching for one that "starts with" isn't very practical.

```
set fixedFolderPath to ":Volumes:FixedFolder1:FixedFolder2:FixedFolder3:"
set varFolderName to "VariableFolder4:"
set finalFolderPath to fixedFolderPath & varFolderName

set partialName to "VariableNumber12345"

tell application "Finder"
    open finalFolderPath as alias
    set finalFolder to (get folders of front window whose name starts with partialName)
    set target of window 1 to finalFolder as alias
end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much anything will need to search the folder names, and there is some overhead from calling the application and the various Apple Events involved.  A shell script (including its overhead) is usually more performant for stuff like this, even more so with an external volume that may not be indexed by Spotlight.  POSIX paths can also be used directly without wrangling with the Finder.

The following example uses [find](https://ss64.com/mac/find.html) to perform a case insensitive search and return the first directory found:

```
set fixedFolderPath to "/Volumes/FixedFolder1/FixedFolder2/FixedFolder3/"
set varFolderName to "VariableFolder4/"
set finalFolderPath to fixedFolderPath & varFolderName
set partialName to "VariableNumber12345"

set found to (do shell script "/usr/bin/find " & quoted form of finalFolderPath & " -type d -maxdepth 1 -iname " & quoted form of (partialName & "*") & " -print -quit") -- name pattern matches everything after partialName
if found is not "" then
   tell application "Finder" to reveal found as POSIX file
else
   (display alert "Directory not found" message "A folder name starting with " & quoted form of partialName & " was not found.")
end if
```

Comment: Thanks red_menace!  Your script is much quicker than mine, although I don't think it'll be quick enough for the larger folder lists - as least it won't time out as mine did. I don't know any shell script language, so I don't know exactly what it's doing, but that gives me something new to learn.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Paulie - The man page shows the various options and expressions, but for this `finalFolderPath` is searched for directories with names of the pattern `partialName`*.  The asterisk will match multiple characters, which is equivalent to "starts with".  I don't have a folder of folders to play with, but a system folder structure containing over 21,000 items took ½ second to find 14 filename matches, searching the entire tree and not returning on the first match, so I'm thinking it should be quick enough.

Comment: That's odd... my script took 61 seconds to complete, with 3300 folders "to choose from". It seems to be a cache issue - where the system wants to read the folder items each time it's opened [instead of remembering what was in there previously].  Maybe it's a Server setting.